# Load report failed in C#.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports-2008

I created one application in C# .Net for viewing crystal report.
But when i try to execute,it shows "load report failed" error message.
May i know the reason.
And what are the  viewer files to be install for viewing report.
Developed the report in Crystal report 2008.

Comment: You may using wrong path of report file. Check out report file physical path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This usually happens. Try the following

1. Check your code. Try this [here](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/01/crystal-reports-sample-in-aspnet.html)
2. Check your data table name and column names. They needs to be the same (case insensitive) as that of database
3. Check your database connectivity.
4. Check if you have any spelling errors in your code that specifies the name of your report file.
5. Check if you have installed all the right components for crystal report to work
6. Open crystal report and try to update connection to your data source
7. Try debugging by removing all fields and blankly showing the report. If it works, it should be problem with your code else it could be problem with crystal report  or connectivity.

Let me know if any of this works for you